# Awkward javascript behavior mapping arrays?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Fails both on chrome and node 8.x

`["4", "5"].map(x => parseInt(x)) // [4, 5]
["4", "5"].map(parseInt) // [4, NaN]`

WHAT?

Comment: Alternative: `.map(Number)`

Comment: This is behaving properly, exactly as documented. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: works fine with .map(parseFloat)

Comment: @AngelSalazar: Because `parseFloat` only accepts 1 parameter.

Comment: Re-open voter: Why? This is an exact duplicate.

Comment: parseInt accepts a second argument (and integer that specifies the radix/base), and map provides its callback a second argument - the array index.

Comment: It is a duplicate, thanks

Comment: I see, basically parseInt gets the number and the index from map

Comment: Yup, precisely!